# GWT & Java EE SessionScoped bean not persisting

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, gwt, cdi

I'm playing w/ EE and want to persist a user session state. I have the session bean here:

```
@Stateful(mappedName = "UserSessionState")
@Named("UserSessionState")
@SessionScoped
@StatefulTimeout(value = 5, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public class UserSessionState implements Serializable
{
    private boolean hasPlayerId = false;
    private String playerId = "";

    public void setRandomPlayerId()
    {
        playerId = UUID.uuid();
        hasPlayerId = true;
    }

    public boolean hasPlayerId()
    {
        return hasPlayerId;
    }

    public String getPlayerId()
    {
        return playerId;
    }
}
```

And a servlet here (GameState is an Application Scoped bean that is working as expected, CustomExtendedHttpServlet is just a simple extension of HttpServlet)

```
public class NewUserJoined extends CustomExtendedHttpServlet
{
    @Inject
    protected GameState gameState;

    @Inject 
    protected UserSessionState user;

    @Override
    protected String doGetImpl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, UserContext userLoginContext)
    {
        if (!user.hasPlayerId())
        {
            user.setRandomPlayerId();
        }        
        String userId = user.getPlayerId();

        if (!gameState.hasUser(userId))
        {
            gameState.addUser(userId, user);
            return "Hi, your ID is: " + user.getPlayerId() + ", there are " + gameState.getUserCount() + " other players here";
        }
        else
        {
            return user.getPlayerId() + " you're already in the game, there are: " + gameState.getUserCount() + " other players here";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's going on, but whenever I call the New User Joined servlet from the same HTTP session, I get this response on the first call (as expected):

"Hi, your ID is: , there are 1 other players here"

Repeating the same servlet call in the same session gives me the same message:
"Hi, your ID is: , there are 2 other players here"
...

It looks like a new instance of User Session State is getting created over and over. Am I doing this correctly?

EDIT 1: Here the code I use to send a request. It appears I'm getting a new session ID with each request, what could cause that?

```
RequestCallback callback = new RequestCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response)
    {
        log(response.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception)
    {
        log(
            "Response Error | "
            + "Exception: " + exception);
    }
};

RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, SERVLET_URL);
rb.setCallback(callback);

try
{
    rb.send();
}
catch (RequestException e)
{
    log("Response Error | "
        + "Exception: " + e);
}
```

Comment: I've been using Chrome Poster and my session does indeed persist from that tool. But the requests from the page itself do not. Is there a way to log the whole request as one big string and compare requests from each origin point to see what's different?

Comment: you have to be careful to use a client that will save/send session cookies when testing in a non-browser.

Comment: I've been using GWT to develop client code, but from what I've been reading, you shouldn't have to deal w/ cookies directly because it's managed under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue,

Turns out I had an old workaround in the GWT client that was changing the host to get around a CORS issue. Because the response didn't match up to the origin, the cookie wasn't getting sent with future servlet GET calls.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a call to request.getSession(true) to make sure an EE HTTPSession is established here?

Comment: request.getSession(true) does work, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for?

If it helps, I logged:

`servletRequest.getSession(true).getId()`

The button from my site produced requests that have unique session IDs, Chrome poster used the same session id.

What could cause new sessions to be created from the client side? (See edit 1 to my original question)




(Not sure why you're getting downvoted, this was a great lead for me)

Comment: your client-code might not be saving/sending session cookies.